# Navigation in Cardboard-Unity using the Cardboard Magnetic sensor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Hi I did a unity scene where the player can walk in a garden, this work fine, but I need when I pull
the magnetic sensor in the cardboard, the player walk without stopping until drop the magnetic sensor.
I used the example for the movement [Navigation Plug-in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w5WdImac2M)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Cursor; // Google Cardboard SDK: Cursor / GazePointer from CardboardMain Prefab
private Vector3 goal;
private NavMeshAgent agent;


public GameObject miPlayer;
private Vector3 startingPosition;
private Vector3 firstFloorPosition;
private Vector3 secondFloorPosition;
private Vector3 thirdFloorPosition;

void Start() {
    this.agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    this.goal = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    startingPosition = miPlayer.transform.localPosition;
}

//Set navigation destination to the position of the cursor
//Ex. Call this from an event trigger on the floor object
public void SetDestinationToCursor() {
    this.goal = Cursor.transform.position;
    MoveToDestination();
}
////code of move of position of the player(Camara)
public void goToFirstFloor(){
    this.goal = firstFloorPosition;
    MoveToDestination();
}
public void goToSecondFloor(){
    this.goal = firstFloorPosition;
    MoveToDestination();
}
public void goToThirdFloor(){
    this.goal = thirdFloorPosition;
    MoveToDestination();
}
////
public void DisableMeshRendererCursor(GameObject cursor){
    cursor.GetComponent <MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
}

public void EnableMeshRendererCursor(GameObject cursor){
    cursor.GetComponent <MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
}


public void ResetDestinationToCursor() {
    this.goal = startingPosition;
    MoveToDestination();
}

public void ExitApplication(){
    Application.Quit ();
}

void MoveToDestination(){
    this.agent.destination = goal; 
}
}
```

I prove other code of the example in the Unity manual but no work [docs.unity3d](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html)